# 'Cursor' object is not iterable

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, iterable

I'm trying to get the location of tweets I've collected using the package `tweepy`:

```
import tweepy as tw

consumer = ...
consumer_secret = ...
access_token = ...
access_token_secret = ...

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

search_words = "delante"
date_since = "2022-01-03"

tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search_tweets,
              q = search_words,
              lang = "es",
              since = date_since)

loc = []
for tweet in tweets:
    loc.append(tweet.user.location)
```

But I get this error:

```
'Cursor' object is not iterable
```

The output of `type(tweets)` is `tweepy.cursor.Cursor`.

What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: what happens if you run dir(tweets)? I think you need to use something like for tweet in tweets.items() but not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tweepy.Cursor` object is indeed not iterable. Call `tweets.items()` to get an iterator over the individual tweets, or `tweets.pages()` to get an iterator over pages worth of tweets.

```
for tweet in tweets.items():
    loc.append(tweet.user.location)
```

[Reference](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/pagination.html)